# Can I store a code(.R file) inside a dataframe column?

Tags: r

I want to store my R code files inside a R data frame column against variables. My dataframe looks like:

metadatatable1:

```
tablename  variable        applicableRcode   
table1     address_key     code1.r           
table1     address_key     code2.r          
table1     zipcode         code2.r           
table2     address_key     code3.r
```

dataframes - table1 and table2:

table1

```
address_key  zipcode
234567       560100
123456       560100
453678       560100
```

table2

```
address_key
54274238
58375235
```

Is it possible to add r code file as a dataframe column value and execute the same to get below output?

```
tablename  variable        applicableRcode   rcodeOutput
table1     address_key     code1.r           98.5
table1     address_key     code2.r           67.2
table1     zipcode         code2.r           100.0
table2     address_key     code3.r           22.8
```

I cannot hardcode the variables, I need to pull the variables from this metadata table, fetch the values of the variables from the table it belongs to, and apply the rules as specified in metadata to get my output.

Much thanks in advance.

Comment: You can store the *name* of a file. How do you want to "execute" it? Like you would with `source("myfunction.R")`? Then how does it get the output back?

Comment: That is the problem @Spacedman. If I can store the name of a R code files against the variables and run the code against the variable, I will store the result in a different dataframe against each variable, and then join it back maybe using sqldf..is it possible? how to do it ?

Comment: Just make sure all the files you specify have the same variable for input and output, and run source with those variables defined in an environment, and get the result value out.

Comment: how to do it if I consider the sample data specified? @Spacedman

Comment: Re your edit. Its still a bit unclear (what are `table1` and `table2`?). You can probably use my solution below with some `get` and `assign` to get and set variables by name.

Comment: Hi @Spacedman, table1 and table2 are my dataframes which contains the values of each variables.., the first dataframe in my example is a metadata table which contains tablename, variablename and applicable code. For example, my code should go to the metadatatable, run the codes against each attribute (for which it needs to get the values from respective dataframes as specified in metadata) and get the output. Re-editing my question again to add table1, table2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's three files, f1, f2 and f3, which are all one-liner R codes that take a variable called `in1` and store their answer in `out`:

```
f1.R
::::::::::::::
out = sqrt(in1)
::::::::::::::
f2.R
::::::::::::::
out = in1*in1
::::::::::::::
f3.R
::::::::::::::
out = in1 * sqrt(in1)
```

Here's a data frame:

```
> d = data.frame(in1 = c(1,2,3,4,5), f = c("f2.R","f1.R","f3.R","f3.R","f2.R"),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> d
  in1    f
1   1 f2.R
2   2 f1.R
3   3 f3.R
4   4 f3.R
5   5 f2.R
```

And here's now you loop over that data frame and call `source`:

```
> lapply(1:nrow(d),function(i){in1=d[i,"in1"];source(d[i,"f"],local=TRUE);out})
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 1.414214

[[3]]
[1] 5.196152

[[4]]
[1] 8

[[5]]
[1] 25
```

You can tidy the output up yourself and do whatever you want with it but the basic principle of what you seem to be trying to do is contained above.

Comment: I tried it out..I agree that the solution is perfect. But I have a far more complex situation here..can you help? I am editing my question with the situation..

Comment: Hi @Spacedman, Much thanks for helping, I have updated my question, please let me know if I sound logical..and if this is possible?

Comment: @DebanjanGhosal If I'm correct, with your updated question you simply have to create the new variable rcodeouput by looping through the variable applicableRcode using source as the function. Something in the lines of `metadatatable1$rcodeOutput <- sapply(metadatatable1$applicableRcode, function(scripts) source(scripts))`. If you need to use the name of the `variable` columns as arguments then index the number of rows and loop through each one.

Comment: I have just updated again to add two dataframes table1 and table2. Please let me know if it is understandable.. @cimentadaj

Comment: @cimentadaj No the solution you provided did not work out :(

Comment: @Spacedman..This is running the code against a particular value of a variable, I want to run code against all values of a variable,

Comment: So for each row use `get` on the tablename to get the table, then use `[[variable]]` to get the column with the name contained in the variable called `variable`.

Comment: Hi @spacedman, didn't get you. I am new and not that proficient yet in R, would you be able to explain in stubs please?